# Invoke SQL Loader from Java Program is not running if file size > 40 MB

Tags: java, oracle11g, architecture, sql-loader

We are trying to load a huge file (say ~1 GB size) into an Oracle database via SQL Loader. I have created a Java program which will execute the SQLLoader command from the program and loader will load the file into the table.

My Code:

```
  public void invokeSQLLoader(){

    String stringCommand="/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin/sqlldr <userId>/<password>@<dburl> control=/u01/hmpoc/HM_EDW_PASSBACK.ctl data=/u01/hmpoc/Passback_Report.csv bad=/u01/hmpoc/PASSBACK.bad discard=/u01/hmpoc/PASSBACK.dsc log=/u01/hmpoc/PASSBACK.log ERRORS=1000000";

    System.out.println("Passing Command::"+stringCommand);

    Process proc = null;

    try {
            System.out.println("Starting procedure call---"+new java.util.Date());

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            proc = rt.exec(stringCommand.trim());

            System.out.println("End Procedure call---"+new java.util.Date());

    }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }/*finally {
            proc.destroy();
    }*/
    System.out.println("SQLLDR Ended");
}
```

Question and query to all the experts:

1. When the file size is ~ 40 MB , we can load data via my Java program.
2. When the file size > 42 MB , Java program runs successfully but data not get loaded with the file. No error or exception shown in the Java console. Where as if I ran the same command from command prompt with same control file and data file it is getting loaded.

Can anyone please help me? If I am missing something or what is the best way to invoke sqlloader from Java program apart from my approach.

Comment: Try adding `proc.waitFor()` to wait until the command is finished (assuming the command doesn't start it's own thread and returns immediately).

Comment: I made the method as Asynchronous so that it can take his own time but as you suggested will try to add for wait() and check.

Comment: You don't seem to be consuming the output and error stream of the process, this can sometimes lead to the application blocking if it actually writes output and the output exceeds the buffer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If you follow the command carefully you could see we are consuming logs and errors as Bad file in unix box directly.

Comment: And are you sure it doesn't output anything to the standard output and error? To be perfectly clear: I don't know sqlldr, I just know that this (not consuming the streams) can sometimes be a problem.

Comment: @AndrewS - As you suggested , I have tried with adding proc.waitFor() methood, certainly it has increased file size which we can invoke. Now we can process till 56 MB. Is there any threshold limit , beyond that Java cannot process via SQL Loader command ?

Comment: No limit that I know of from a java perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I did not make any changes in my above mentioned Java code. I have only added **DIRECT=TRUE** in my control file. It works. Now I am able to load till 1 GB size file.

Thanks all who read my problem and tried to give answer.